# Backbonejs - the correct approach to on - off the event per render on button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

In app, I have 3 buttons, all are calling the render function and using same template as well. but different buttons are on click, I would like to `off` the other event `click focus change keyup` bindings from previous form `inputs` rendering.

I can use the jquery's `on()` and `off()` approach. But i confused to utilize that. as well i find that there is even better way to using the `event.spacename` in jquery. Any one recommend me the right approach whether need to use the  `event.spacename` or not?

here is my sample app code (events not binded on inputs);

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({});

var View = Backbone.View.extend({
    el:'#container',
    template:_.template($('#allForm').html()),
    events:{
        'click #add' : 'add',
        'click #update' : 'update',
        'click #enquire' : 'inquire'
    },
    initialize : function(){
        console.log("i am called")
    },
    render:function(){
        $('.formHolder').html(this.template);
    },
    add : function() {
this.render();
},
    update : function() {
this.render();
},
    inquire : function() {
this.render();
}  
});
var myModel = new Model;
var myView = new View({model: myModel})
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3gwebtrain/LBHwV/1/)

Comment: @mu, ok. But can you tell me how to off the binding the view event between re-rendering the same template?

Comment: I don't know my approach is correct or wrong. here is my updated live demo, where nothing works properly. i would like to make all are work correctly to keep in mind the adding event listeners and remove the same too.. http://jsfiddle.net/3gwebtrain/LBHwV/2/

Comment: Basically i am trying to use the single form for all needs and adding removing listeners. Same time i need to fech the data from any input event accure.

Comment: hmm.. may be ok. But I decide to make it short as much as. thanks for your continuing support. you are a good man.